# How can I use BeautifulSoup to find all the links in a page pointing to a specific domain?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I use BeautifulSoup to find all the links in a page pointing to a specific domain?

Answer (score 8):

Use SoupStrainer,

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import re

# Find all links
links = SoupStrainer('a')
[tag for tag in BeautifulSoup(doc, parseOnlyThese=links)]

linkstodomain = SoupStrainer('a', href=re.compile('example.com/'))
```

Edit: Modified example from official doc.

Comment: I would be more selective with the regex; that one could result in false positives.

Comment: @Ignacio - right, this example has that caveat - the regex should obviously be as detailed as possible so as to avoid those false positives.

Comment: No, you should typically not try to parse html with regex, here is an elaborate explanation(s) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @subiet, this example is not using regex to parse the HTML. It is being used to limit the results to a known subset by matching the href attribute.